# mod rewrite for all requests after a directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex-negation

I am looking to do a rewrite for all requests after a directory in a url, but cant for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Essentially looking for:

url.com/directory/anything/after/the/directory/

So if any requests com to url.com/directory/ regardless of what comes after it is redirected back to the index that was before the directory (ie. url.com)

I tried with a regex pattern: /forex/.?(.*)

But i'm really not getting anywhere.

Can anybody kick me in the right direction.  I was essentially going for:

```
RewriteRule \/forex\/.?(.*) inxe.php
```

This didnt work though.

Appreciate all responses, thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with `RewriteRule /forex/?.* index.php` (very slightly modified from your rule)

Comment: Try this: RewriteRule ^(.*)forex(.*)$ index.php [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before any rule make sure you write RewriteEngine on

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^/?dir/((?!index).+)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

This will redirect

- /dir/foo/bar (excluding the directory index file)

to

- /index.php